# parsing XML - how to iterate through a child node and assign value to each

Tags: vbscript, xmldom

I have the following XML I am trying to parse:

```
  <host>
     <object>
        <objectname>Server1</objectname> 
        <objecttype>host</objecttype> 
        <location>USA</location>
        <fcadapterports>
          <port>
             <portwwn>1000-0000-CCXX-B2B4</portwwn> 
          </port>
          <port>
             <portwwn>1000-0000-AW8D-23AB</portwwn> 
          </port>
     </object>
   </host>
```

So I can get values until I get to the portwwn and I'm in way over my head.

So far I have this -

```
 Set objHosts = objConfigXml.selectNodes("//host/object")
     For Each objMap in objHosts
     Set objSingle = objMap
        objSheet.Cells(iY,1).Value = objSingle.selectSingleNode("objectname").Text
        objSheet.Cells(iY,2).Value = objSingle.selectSingleNode("objecttype").Text
        objSheet.Cells(iY,3).Value = NEED HELP
        objSheet.Cells(iY,4).Value = NEED HELP
        objSheet.Cells(iY,5).Value = objSingle.selectSingleNode("location").Text
```

Next I have to retrieve the multiple values for portwwn and assign those to the next cells in the spreadsheet like objSheet.Cells(iY,3) and objSheet.Cells(iY,4), etc.

Comment: I need to take the two values: 1000-0000-CCXX-B2B4
1000-0000-AW8D-23AB and insert these two values into these lines:  objSheet.Cells(iY,3).Value = ???? and objSheet.Cells(iY,4).Value = ??????

Answer (score 0):

This demo script:

```
  Dim sXml : sXml = Join(Array( _
     "<host>" _
   , "  <object>" _
   , "   <objectname>Server1</objectname>" _
   , "   <objecttype>host</objecttype>" _
   , "   <location>USA</location>" _
   , "   <fcadapterports>" _
   , "    <port>" _
   , "       <portwwn>1000-0000-CCXX-B2B4</portwwn>" _
   , "    </port>" _
   , "    <port>" _
   , "       <portwwn>1000-0000-AW8D-23AB</portwwn>" _
   , "    </port>" _
   , "   </fcadapterports>" _
   , "  </object>" _
   , "</host>" _
  ))
  Dim sXPath   : sXPath       = "/host/object/fcadapterports"
  Dim objMSXML : Set objMSXML = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
  objMSXML.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
  objMSXML.async = False
  objMSXML.loadXml sXml

  If 0 = objMSXML.parseError Then
     Dim ndFnd : Set ndFnd = objMSXML.SelectSingleNode(sXPath)
     If ndFnd Is Nothing Then
        WScript.Echo qq(sXPath), "not found"
     Else
        WScript.Echo ndFnd.xml
        WScript.Echo ndFnd.childNodes(0).tagName, "1", ndFnd.childNodes(0).firstChild.text
        WScript.Echo ndFnd.childNodes(1).tagName, "2", ndFnd.childNodes(1).firstChild.text
        Dim nCol : nCol = 3
        Dim ndChild
        For Each ndChild In ndFnd.childNodes
            WScript.Echo "col", nCol, ndChild.SelectSingleNode("portwwn").text
            nCol = nCol + 1
        Next
     End If
  Else
     WScript.Echo objMSXML.parseError.reason
  End If
```

output #1:

```
End tag 'object' does not match the start tag 'fcadapterports'.
```

output #2 (after closing the tag):

```
<fcadapterports>
        <port>
                <portwwn>1000-0000-CCXX-B2B4</portwwn>
        </port>
        <port>
                <portwwn>1000-0000-AW8D-23AB</portwwn>
        </port>
</fcadapterports>
port 1 1000-0000-CCXX-B2B4
port 2 1000-0000-AW8D-23AB
col 3 1000-0000-CCXX-B2B4
col 4 1000-0000-AW8D-23AB
```

should show

1. The how and why of error checking to catch blunders like your missing `</fcadapterports>`
2. Access to childNodes via index, firstChild, and For Each
3. Working with extra info - e.g. column numbers - when looping over a (childNodes) collection

**Update wrt comments:**

This

```
Set nodeslist = objConfigXml.selectNodes("//host/object/fcadapterports/port")
For i = 0 To nodeslist.Length -1 Step 2
    objSheet.Cells(iY,4).Value = nodeslist(i).Text & nodeslist(i+1).text
Next
```

kind of works with 2 issues:

1. It puts all the values in a single excel cell (because
   objSheet.Cells(iY,4) = ... puts everything each time in
   objSheet.Cells(iY,4))
2. Its not iterating through - its only picking the last value (because
   the stepped counted loop is nonsense (and exactly the opposite of
   the For Each I proposed))

I'm still tempted to write a disclaimer:

> This answer is to be used by programmers, not by copy and paste artist
>   who ignore all advice.

OTOH, maybe changing the line

```
WScript.Echo "col", nCol, ndChild.SelectSingleNode("portwwn").text
```

to

```
WScript.Echo ndChild.SelectSingleNode("portwwn").text, "should go in objSheet.Cells(iY," & nCol & ").Value"
```

new output

```
cscript 22821889.vbs
..
1000-0000-CCXX-B2B4 should go in objSheet.Cells(iY,3).Value
1000-0000-AW8D-23AB should go in objSheet.Cells(iY,4).Value
```

will help to understand what I meant with "Working with extra info - e.g. column numbers - when looping over a (childNodes) collection"

Comment: Sorry, there is just none of this that is working.  I'm trying to fit this code into the code I already have.  I already have a set obj.ConfigXml = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM") statement.  I have tried every variation of your code I can think of to make it work within the existing and it's not.

Comment: This kind of works with 2 issues: 1. It puts all the values in a single excel cell and 2. Its not iterating through - its only picking the last value: Set nodeslist = objConfigXml.selectNodes("//host/object/fcadapterports/port") For i = 0 To nodeslist.Length -1 Step 2 objSheet.Cells(iY,4).Value = nodeslist(i).Text & nodeslist(i+1).text Next